# Atribuição de valores a variáveis com repetições

Tags: loop, variáveis, visualg

Estava fazendo um exercício da sequência de Fibonacci e fiquei bastante confuso com a questão de atribuição de valores às variáveis dentro de repetições. Encontrei uma solução como que por sorte e acabei no fim não entendendo meu próprio código, por essa questão de confusão em relação às variáveis.

Eis o código:

```
Algoritmo "Sequência de Fibonacci"
Var
   C, PN, SN: Inteiro
Inicio
   EscrevaL(" Sequência de Fibonacci (15 primeiros números) ")
   EscrevaL
   PN := 0 // Linha desnecessária, pois o valor 0 é atribuído por padrão às variáveis numéricas em Visualg.
   // Porém, por questões de entendimento eu achei melhor atribuir o valor à variável nesse caso.
   Escreva(PN) // >>> 0
   SN := 1
   Para C := 1 Ate 7 Faca
      SN := SN + PN // SN recebe último valor atribuído a si + último valor atribuído a PN
      Escreva(SN) // >>> 1, 2, 5, 13, 34, 89, 233
      PN := PN + SN // PN recebe último valor atribuído a si + último valor atribuído a SN
      Escreva(PN) // >>> 1, 3, 8, 21, 55, 144, 377
   FimPara
   EscrevaL
FimAlgoritmo
```

Vocês conseguem me dizer se meus comentários são esclarecedores, ou meu entendimento em relação ao código ainda é raso...? Por exemplo se fosse para eu explicar para alguém o código a seguir eu acabaria me perdendo totalmente sem os comentários, pois a ideia de atribuir o valor de uma variável a ela mesma já me deixa meio confuso.
Eu estaria certo em dizer que a repetição cria várias linhas de código independentes uma da outra? Ou seria apenas isso que vejo na tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seus comentários em relação ao código são sim pertinentes, e devem ser feitos dessa forma mesmo, pois comenta-se para que outros posssam entender ou até mesmo pra você entender.
Não importa quanto tempo de experiência com programação você tenha, é impossível decorar todos os comandos de uma linguagem, temos que sempre relembrar e pesquisar, e comentários ajudam bastante nisso.

Agora, quanto à atribuição do valor de uma variável nela mesma, como em:

```
SN := SN + PN
```

Podemos analisar a função acima como um simples contador. Contadores são muito comuns em laços de repetição, servem como condição para finalizar o mesmo.
Ao atribuir o valor de uma variável nela mesma acrescido de outro valor dentro de um loop, há o aumento constante do valor dessa variável, ou seja, é arescentado repetidas vezes um valor e este armezenado continuamente na variável.

Outra dica, no caso da linha desnecessária: `PN := 0` é melhor que você a retire daí e coloque um comentário explicando que realmente não precisa atribuir esse valor, por já ser um padrão. Deixe a parte do código para funcionamento prático, e os comentários para fins de entendimento.

Comment: Eu até entendendo que a estrutura serve para aumentar um valor progressivamente dentro do laço de repetição, mas fico meio confuso nessa lógica. De qualquer forma obrigado pela resposta! Acho que nem sempre é tão necessário entender os minímos detalhes das coisas, vou tentar continuar estudando programação, dominando o básico assim as coisas vão se esclarecendo.

Comment: Conforme você for praticando mais programação e entrando em outras linguagens conceitos assim vão ficando mais claros, pode ter certeza !